# Which language is used for the development of querykaro.com?

Tags: frontend, backend, web-deployment

Which language is used for the development of [Querykaro.com](https://querykaro.com) website?

Comment: Ask the creators of that site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to curl the headers of the website with `curl --HEAT https://querykaro.com` and then the `X-Powered-By` header will contain the information of the programming language used in the website, in this case it is PHP 7.4.23

```
$ curl --HEAD https://querykaro.com/
HTTP/2 200
date: Sat, 25 Sep 2021 06:35:44 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.23
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Wordpress.

Download "Wappalyzer" addon to Google Chrome, and you will se additional info like JS libraries.